# "Could not load type" from app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I've got a functioning program I inherited that works as a service at the moment.   All that service does is call a method in another class, so I'm trying to write a winform project I can run so I can work on itit.   I've copy+pasted the app.config file over and changed the name of the project over to servicetester, to a new non-service project.  I've also copied various bits of code other code from the service and it all builds.   I get the following message when I try and run the project using the line

```
var connectionManagerDataSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CustomConfigurationSection") as clsCustomConfigurationSection;
```

message

```
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for CustomConfigurationSection: Could not load type 'servicetester.Configuration.CustomConfigurationSect
ion' from assembly 'servicetester'. (D:\\thepath\\servicetester\\bin\\Debug\\servicetester.vshost.exe.Config line 4)"
```

inner exception

```
"System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'servicetester.Configuration.CustomConfigurationSection' from assembly 'servicetester'.
   at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
```

This is the app.config which apart from the project name is the same as the original service project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
      <section name="CustomConfigurationSection" type="servicetester.Configuration.CustomConfigurationSection, servicetester" />
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
          <section name="Proj.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <CustomConfigurationSection>
    <EwsConfiguration username="a@b.com" password="letmein" version="2" emailStoreLocation="\\serverpath\" url="https://emailplace" subscriptionConnectionLifetime="15" debug="true"/>
  </CustomConfigurationSection>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Proj.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Proj_Email_Log" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://path</value>
      </setting>
    </Proj.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

There isn't a path to
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\MYCOMPANY\MYAPP.exe_Url_longnastyhash9982749827349879\1.0.0.0\user.config
or any other places along that lines I've read to try deleting

I've cleaned and rebuilt everything

The winform app is the same version as the service in terms of .NET framework
Those are the most common things that Google says it can be.   Any other ideas?
THanks

Comment: Wherever Configuration.CustomConfigurationSection is, it is not accessible to the servicetester project. You may be missing an include, or you may need to copy over that class to the servicetester project.

Comment: I've copied that over and (hopefully) all the necessary ones.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have ran into the same problem too.

Comment: I deleted the project, added a new one building everything up from scratch, ignoring the existing code.   The code in the new testing project turns out identical to the old testing project but works.   I think it might be something to do with the project file/settings/properties, I thought I chose all the same options both times but I don't know.   I created a console project as well which worked first time.   Maybe give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You  need  the name of the section group and the custom section.

```
var confSection = (CustomSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MCustomConfigurationSection/applicationSettings");
```

Here you have sample config with sample customAppSetting and sectionGroup

App.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="CustomConfigurationSection">
      <section name="customAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <customAppSettingsGroup>
    <customAppSettings>
      <add key="Key1" value="val1"/>
      <add key="Key2" value="val2"/>
    </customAppSettings>
  </customAppSettingsGroup>
</configuration>
```

Usage:

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CustomConfigurationSection/customAppSettings") as NameValueCollection;
var val1 = section["Key1"];
var val2 = section["Key2"];
```

Comment: Gave that a go but it  brings back the same error message

Comment: Use custom section as i show and it will be work. Try edit also your appconfig.